# C Language: lookup in char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, lookup

I'm studying C language on my own. Can someone give me a hint on problem below? (Just a hint is good and I'll work on it from there.) Thanks.

The symptom is that the index number printed is always 0.

```
print("\n\n  Lookdown: start with a value and get the index of the match  \n");
  char myArrayOfLetters2[] = {'w','x','y','z'};
  char myLookUpValue = "y";
  int myResultIndexNumber;
  int myArrayCounter;

  for (myArrayCounter=0; myArrayCounter<sizeof(myArrayOfLetters2); myArrayCounter++){
    if (myArrayOfLetters2[myArrayCounter] == myLookUpValue){
            myResultIndexNumber=myArrayCounter;} //found
  } // loop thorugh all members of array
print("myLookUpValue of 'y' returned index number of %d",myResultIndexNumber);
```

Comment: `sizeof(myArrayOfLetters2)` returns the size of the memory address to the first element of the array.  I'm assuming this is not what you want.

In this case it works basically by accident since `sizeof(char*)` is 4, but if you expand or shrink the array it will not work.

Comment: @cmbasnett: No, no it doesn't. `sizeof an_array` returns the size of the array, in bytes.  If it were `sizeof some_pointer` it would return the size of the pointer.  Neither returns the size of the first element.  That would be `sizeof some_array[0]`.  The compiler knows how to figure out the size of an array.  Arrays are not pointers.  The loop is fine because `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

Comment: @cmbasnett: Also, arrays cannot be "expanded" or "shrunk".  Not sure what you meant by that.

Comment: You're right, I was wrong about the `sizeof` call returning the size of the pointer to the first element.  The expanding and shrinking array I meant if he decided to manually change the size of that array, not a dynamic resize of course.

Comment: @cmbasnett: Ah, ok, that makes sense.  I probably should have bveen able to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char myLookUpValue = "y";
```

`"y"` is not a char, it's a string (`const char[]`).  Arrays decay to pointers to their first element when appropriate. You're converting the address of that array (a pointer to its first element) to a char (turn on your warnings). You wanted:

```
char myLookUpValue = 'y';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes:

```
char myLookUpvalue = 'y';
```

Answer (score 0):

this is really simple I think, all I shall say is that you are assigning a string "y" to a char. Line 3 should be char myLookUpValue = 'y';

Your code will assign a lowest 8 bits of a pointer to constant string containing 'y' which is a memory location and will be very unlikely to equal the char code of 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

One major problem is here:

```
char myLookUpValue = "y";
```

The expression `"y"` is a *string literal* and has type "2-element array of `char`" with the contents `{'y', 0}`.  To define a *character literal*, use single quotes instead:

```
char myLookupValue = 'y';
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In your code, the expression`"y"` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and while it's being used to initialize something in a declaration, that something isn't an array of `char`, so it's converted to a pointer type and its value is the *address* of first letter of the string in storage.  That address value is then converted to type `char` and assigned to `myLookupValue`; the result is most likely not any of `'w'`, `'x'`, `'y'`, or `'z'`. so the comparison fails.